# jquery and dynamic forms help?

Tags: jquery, django, dynamic

I'm very new to jquery, and I'm trying to make a dynamic form in the following manner (and its not working). I want the form to have an initial value of "hello" as stated in the header region.

I understand that you can do this easily with html (with the value parameter), but I have a much larger goal in mind that requires the value to be dynamic.

Anyway, I just can't seem to get it to work, so help please. Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Logging In Test</title>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.js">
    var value = "hello";
    $('#login [name=firstname]').val(value)
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="login">
    <input type = "text" name="firstname">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `$(document).ready();`  http://api.jquery.com/ready/
like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var value = "hello";
    $('#login [name=firstname]').val(value)
});
```

to set initial values after document fully loads and DOM is created properly

Answer (score 0):

there is a problem with how and when you insert jquery try the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Logging In Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="login">
    <input type = "text" name="firstname">
</form>



<script type = "text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">
    var value = "hello";
    $('#login [name=firstname]').val(value)
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Actually, I found a link that is quite helpful:

http://www.jason-palmer.com/2008/08/jquery-plugin-form-field-default-value/

I'm going to try that out later today.

Comment: Hmm, didn't know that the jquery should go there, I'll give that a try

Comment: scripts should be places in header, but the problem is not releated to position of `script` tag in page

Comment: depends on what you want to achieve, scripts in the body make sure the elements are created before js execution just like `$(document).ready()` does, and it downloads the external JS last so it doesnt block initial page rendering.